# Upgrade drupal 8.2.3

Tags: upgrade, drupal-8

I have followed the steps to upgrade my site from **drupal 8.2.2** to **drupal 8.2.3.**
That is I have:

- removed core and vendor folders
- removed all topfiles
- downloaded, extracted and copied new core to folder
- ran update.php

`update.php` tells me there's no pending updates and my core version still says 8.2.2 and "there is an update available".

**Note:** My server does not allow for drush so I have to go "commando style"! :P

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have the Opcache settings to not revalidate on every request. Try reloading/restarting your Apache or PHP-FPM.

Also, confirm these options

- opcache.revalidate_freq=0
- opcache.validate_timestamps=0

Comment: Any hint on how to do that at one.com?